# SQL Server Reporting Services - Subscription Failure

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I am attempting to setup e-mail subscriptions to for a SSRS report.  In the subscriptions tab I continue to get the Result message "Failure sending mail: Failure sending mail." There also is no trace log created that contains this error message. The path for the logs I've been checking is C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/MRSR13.MSSQLSERVER/Reporting Services/LogFiles. Does anyone know the best way to trouble shoot what the error is specifically resulting from without access to a log file? Any help is much appreciated.

I've tried changing the subscription parameters but have had no success. Always the same vague result message, "Failure sending mail: Failure sending mail."

Comment: Sounds like your SSRS server doesn't have the email server setup correctly. This is setup server side in the Report Server Configuration Manager.